# PyQGIS with Pycharm CE 4.5

Tags: pyqgis, pycharm

I'm able to run PyQGIS on my Mac (OSX 10.10.3) through the Python (2.7) console and through execution of Python files through my terminal. In order to do so, I added the following to my bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/
```

However, when running the same scripts in PyCharm, I get the following package not found errors:

```
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

In PyCharm settings, I've tried adding the following Environment Variables to Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console:

```
PATH - /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/
PYTHONPATH - /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH - /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/
```

...but to no avail. I've tried playing around with adding/removing semicolons and $VARS but no joy.

This problem is quite vexing as I'm able to import the packages without problem in PyCharm's Python console. I'm using a virtualenv that is setup within my PyCharm.